# How do you replace the color of regions of text in a content editable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

Let's suppose I have a content editable `pre` tag and a button, like this:

```
<pre id="input" contenteditable>
hello world!
how is everything today?

I like cherries
</pre>
<button id="colorify">Colorify!</button>
```

When the `colorify` button is pressed, I would like the text to alternate between three different colors by character. It should look something like this:

[image]

This is my intention, expressed in pseudo-Javascript:

```
$("#colorify").click(function() {
  var input = $("#input"), text = input.text(),
   colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"];
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    input.changeColorOfRange(i, 1, colors[i % 3]);
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, there is no `changeColorOfRange` function that accepts a character index, a string length, and a color to do this.

I've seen RTF editors in Javascript, and I've looked into some of their APIs, but they only seem to allow changing the color of selected text, instead of programatically changing the color of arbitrary regions of text.

How can I programmatically change the color of arbitrary regions of text inside of a contenteditable element?

Comment: I don't think I follow you...Can you post an image of what's the actual behavior that's supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap each letter in a span to color each letter.

http://jsfiddle.net/SJqpr/1/

```
$("#colorify").click(function() {
    var input = $("#input"),
        text = input.text(),
        colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"];

    $('#input').html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var $span = $('<span>' + text[i] + '</span>').css('color', colors[i % 3]);
        $('#input').append($span);
    }
});
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but I had the same solution. There is a a bug: type in more text in the box on a new line. When you colorify, the newline disappears.

Comment: I've been trying to make it work with my particular solution and a `contentEditable` element but you're right, new lines are ignored when converted. It seems like each new line is a `div`, I guess you can colorify each div and then append them again in the same order somehow...

Comment: @PeterOlson - I see. This is closer, http://jsfiddle.net/SJqpr/2/. It works the first time, but not subsequent times. I grabbed from another SO question some code that wraps all text nodes with spans.

Answer (score 0):

This is another posible solution but maybe not quite what you're looking for. There might be many consecutive characters with the same color since it's totally random. I'm sure this could be improved...

**html:**

```
<p id="input" contentEditable></p><br/>
<button>Colorify</button>
```

**js:**

```
var colorify = function(str) {

    var chars = str.split(''),
        colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'],
        spans = '';

    $.each(chars, function(idx, value){
        spans += '<span style="color:' + 
            colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)] +
            '">'+ value +'</span>';
    });

    $('#input').empty().append(spans);
};

$('button').click(function(){ colorify($('#input').text()); });
```